# Switch between layouts like gdb in lldb

Tags: c, lldb

lldb by default shows assembly code unless I use breakpoints (with `breakpoint set -f file.c -l xx`) where it shows source on running `next`.

In gdb I can use `layout src` to switch to source mode, how can I switch to source mode in lldb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple settings you need to switch to do this.  I made a little Python command to coordinate toggling them back & forth here:

https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/lldb/examples/python/disassembly_mode.py

You can put that in your ~/.lldb directory and in your ~/.lldbinit do:

command script import ~/.lldb/disassembly_mode.py

That will give it the name toggle-disassembly, but you can call it anything you want by changing the last line in the .py file.

Comment: The script seems to run, but this I see only [assembly](https://i.imgur.com/ZjY8nwU.png), even in `gui` mode
I can see the source with breakpoints even now

Comment: The gui mode should have some gui affordance for determining the source printing, so I'm not surprised it doesn't obey the stop print settings.  The toggle-disassembly script toggles between pure source & pure disassembly because that's what I like.  The settings work in combination so you can get it to display both source & assembly by editing the script.  To get interleaved source & disassembly you have to use the `disassemble -m` command.  If you want that you can set the stop printing to not print anything and add a stop-hook that does `disassemble -m -p`.